# What is this Tomcat Error Status?

Tags: server, tomcat

I have just performed the following steps, and at the end I don't understand this Tomcat Status Message:

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container Loaded: 
loaded (/run/systemd/generator.late/tomcat.service; bad; vendor prese  Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

```
$ sudo mkdir -p -v /opt/java/64
$ sudo mv -v ~/Downloads/jre1.8.0_111 /opt/java/64
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java
$ sudo apt-get remove icedtea-8-plugin
$ ln -s /opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
$ sudo groupadd tomcat
$ sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
$ sudo apt install tomcat8
$ sudo apt-get install tomcat8 tomcat8-docs tomcat8-admin tomcat8-examples
```

I then ran the following command and and pasted username information in the `/etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml` file.

```
$ gksu leafpad /etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml
$ systemctl restart tomcat8    
$ gksu leafpad /run/systemd/generator.late/tomcat.service
```

I pasted the following in the `/run/systemd/generator.late/tomcat.service` file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_111

Environment=CATALINA_PID=/run/tomcat8.pid

Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat8

Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat8

Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'

Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh

ExecStop=/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I finally ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ant git
$ systemctl restart tomcat8
$ sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

This is where I get such status message above. I hope someone can help.

1. Is such message normail?
2. I think I need help with the command above as it does not match with the content of the file tomcat.service.
3. I super need help with the content of tomcat.service. Can it be that I pasted someting wrong in there?

My OS is Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I know why now. It has to do with the command below.

$ sudo systemctl status tomcat

It is supposed to be

$ sudo systemctl status tomcat8

Thanks